# Copy lines matching pattern, then substitute

Tags: search, substitute

I want to search file for pattern, duplicate every line that matches that pattern, then in perform substitution on each duplicated line.

Suppose file looks like this:

```
a 1
a 2
b 1
b 2
c 1
c 2
```

I want to duplicate each line matching `/2`, then substitute `2` with `3` (`s/2/3`), and end up with file:

```
a 1
a 2
a 3
b 1
b 2
b 3
c 1
c 2
c 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with a `:g` command which marks all lines on which to act and then run a combination of a `:t` (copy) and `:s` (substitute) command.

Something like this should work:

```
g/2$/t.|s/2/3
```

This executes on each line matching `2$` the following command: `:t.|s/2/3`
which means, copy the current line and afterwards replace the 2 by 3 in the current (copied) line.

Comment: Wow, that was awesome!